# SQL Server query with group as a count

Tags: sql-server

I have no idea where to start with this. I'm developing a forum and need a list of trending topics. The way this works is that I need a list of topics and ordered by the amount of messages in reply to that topic since a certain date time. But only unique messages (so if a user reply to a topic 100 times and another topic has 2 replied by 2 different userid's then the second is higher)

I guess it needs to retrieve the topic and then do a count of messages linked to that topic id grouped by the userid of the messages (so if a user replies 100 times to a topic it only counts as 1) and then sort the topics by this count.

Here is what I guess is needed from tables

`@lastvisit` will contain the `DateTime`, so its all messages for the topic which are after this datetime. So I can call it eg datetime now - 2 hours will be the trending topics for last 2 hours

`Topics` table

```
TopicId
TopicTitle
Active (has to be active = True)
```

`Messages` table

```
TopicId
MessageCreationDate
UserId
Active (has to be active = 1)
```

No idea where to start with this, something I need to learn is SQL

Based on lc's answer I have came up with this as a basis

```
SELECT
    T.TopicTitle, T.TopicId, UniqueUserCount
FROM 
    Topics AS T
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT
         COUNT(distinct M.UserId) as UniqueUserCount, M.TopicId
     FROM 
         Messages AS M
     WHERE 
         M.TopicId = T.TopicId
     GROUP BY M.TopicId) AS m
GROUP BY 
    T.TopicId, TopicTitle, UniqueUserCount
ORDER BY 
    UniqueUserCount DESC
```

Comment: So you want to calculate sorting weight for each comment and then depending on that weight you want to sort out the data. This is pure business logic it's better to do it in the code side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `COUNT DISTINCT`. This will count only the distinct (unique) values of the column in question. So you would group by topic and count distinct users.

In your example, this query:

```
select count(distinct UserId) as UniqueUserCount, TopicId
from Messages
group by TopicId
```

where topic 13 has 100 messages from a single user, and topic 42 has 1 message each from 2 users, will return results like:

```
UniqueUserCount  | TopicId
              1  |      13
              2  |      42
```